# Fill automatically a textarea

Tags: javascript

How can I fill automatically a textarea when opening a web-page.

I have 2 saved strings (login and password) and I must set it to login and password text areas on web-page. I haven't text areas id (or name). I'm ios developer, and I need such functions in java script... Сan someone help or give some useful link?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific?

You can set the value with jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/val/

$('yourInputTextArea').val(yourString);

Comment: By textareas you do mean input fields? Using plain javascript I suppose, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the ID or name, you can grab the first textarea on the page. The `[0]` represents the first, so incremement it for the second, third and so on. [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a node list that you can use like an array, so it can be looped if the total number of textareas is not known.

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = "Some value";
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxwWW/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

I am assuming this is your HTML

```
<input type="text" id="username"/>
<input type="password" id="password"/>
```

In JavaScript you could do this to populate your textboxes

```
document.getElementById("username").value = "Your value";
document.getElementById("password").value = "Your value";
```

If you want more help, you have to be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6Gkf/1/

**CODE**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHTML = "login";
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[1].innerHTML = "password";
```

hope it helps